# How can I use strrev to reverse a string?

Tags: string

I want to reverse the string array result but when i run this code in online compiler it says "strrev was not declared". I don't understand this.

```
for(j=1;j<=test;j++)
{
cin >> input;
strcpy(result,input);
length = strlen(result);         
strrev(result);
cout<<"Case "<<j<<": ";
for(i = 0;i<=length;i++) 
{
if(result[i]==input[i])
p=0;
else
{
p=1;
break;
}
}
if(p==0)
cout<<"Yes"<<endl;
else
cout<<"No"<<endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Where does `strrev` come from?  It's not part of the Standard library.  You will have to include the header file that defines it, and include that.

You are using C++ (`cout`) so don't use char arrays and strlen, but use std::string instead.  (You will need `#include <string>` at the top of your file)

```
    for(int j=0;j<test;j++)  // Life is easier if you get in the habit of writing loops like this
    {
        std::string input;  // Don't declare variables until you need them.
        std::cin >> input;
        // Initialize 'result' as the reverse of input directly.
        const std::string result(input.crbegin(), input.crend());
        const char* const answer = (input == result) ? "Yes" : "No";
        std::cout << "Case " << (j+1) << ": " answer << std::endl;  // Offset test case for output.
    }
```

You'll notice that my code is a LOT shorter than yours - I'm getting the library to do nearly all the heavy lifting.  I've also avoided `using namespace std`.  In the long term, it makes your code clearer if you leave it out.

I'm also tempted to write a function `fromCin`, which returns the string.  Then I would write  `const std::string input = fromCin();` which has the lovely result that all my variables in the loop are constants.